# Use the same connection for multiple Logstash configurations

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using Logstash 2.4.1 to load data to Elasticsearch 2.4.6.
I have the following Logstash config:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@database:1521:db1"
        jdbc_user => "user"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        jdbc_driver_library => "ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        parameters => { "id" => 1 }
        statement => "SELECT modify_date, userName from user where id = :id AND modify_date >= :sql_last_value"

        schedule => "*/1 * * * *"
        tracking_column => modify_date
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "index1"
        document_type  => "USER"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

So, for each minute, it goes to the database to check if there is new data for Elastic.
It works perfectly, but there is one problem:
We have around 100 clients, and they are all in the same database instance.

That means I have 100 scripts and will have 100 instances of Logstash running, meaning 100 open connections:

```
nohup ./logstash -f client-1.conf Logstash startup
nohup ./logstash -f client-2.conf Logstash startup
nohup ./logstash -f client-3.conf Logstash startup
nohup ./logstash -f client-4.conf Logstash startup
nohup ./logstash -f client-5.conf Logstash startup
and so on...
```

This is just bad.

Is there any way I can use the same connection for all my scripts ?
The only difference between all those scripts is the parameter id and the index name, each client will have a diferent id and a different index:

```
parameters => { "id" => 1 }
index => "index1"
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with the JDBC input but I assume that it will index each column in a own field inside of each document (per row).

So than you don't have to filter on a specific user in the query, but just add all the rows to same index. After that you can filter with Kibana on a specific user (assumed that you want use Kibana to analyze the data). Filtering can also be done with a ES query.

With that approach you only need 1 logstash configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to implement this, you will need to play with them to find the one that works for you.

In my experience with JDBC input, all columns in your select become fields in a document. Each row returned by the JDBC input will result in a new document.

If you select the client id instead of using it as a parameter/predicate you can then use the id in your elastic search output and append it to the index output.

Each document (row) will then be routed to an index based on the client id. 
This is very similar to their date based index strategy and is supported by default in logstash.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index

Just remember that all columns names are automatically lowercased when logstash brings them in. They are case sensitive once in logstash.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 1 index to each customer, I decided to user 1 index for all clients and making the filter of the clients on the query.
Works good, no performance issues.

Check this for more info: [My post on elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/use-the-same-connection-for-multiple-logstash-configurations/147736)